# Budget allocation using multiplicative regression model

Tags: regression, python, predictive-models, marketing

I need your help to define the optimal budget allocation using a marketing mix model. I have built a multiplicative model to account for diminishing return and interaction between my IVs, and I am asked to decide how to allocate a 30% budget more compared to the previous quarter (Q2).

How could I do?

I would like to find the optimal amount of budget allocated to each of my IVs.

I built two different multiplicative models: one for a subset containing data about Q2, and one for a dataset containing data about Q3 in order to derive the different impact on my IVs in different quarters.

Subsequently, I increased the value of the IVs which have a greater impact in Q3 compared to Q2. I use this updated data to predict my new output in order to find the way to maximize my sales.

Basically I am playing around allocating different amount of budget across 3 IVs (33% 33% 33%; 50% 25% 25% etc..)

Would you have a better solution?